# Parse body and get name of the file in Node.js without frameworks

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I need to send a file in the body and save it locally on Node.js server. I actually managed that but I can not get the extension of the file. I can manually set the extension but I need to save file with deferent extensions.

```
  const fileName = 'file.jpg'

  const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);

  request.pipe(writeStream)
```

I was able to get the extension from 'content-type' header in case when I choose type of the body as 'binary' in Postman but when I use 'form-data' the header changes into something like `form-data; boundary=--------------------------778695892531610719787747"`

I was trying to parse the body myself using `req.on('data', () => ...)` but no luck.

P.S. I'm not using any libraries here so using something like multer, body-parser or express is not an option.

Comment: Frameworks != libraries. By not using multer, etc, you have to implement parts of HTTP protocol yourself, more specifically multipart body, IIRC filename is in content-disposition. What is the context for this question? Is this a homework? I don't see good reasons to not use libs where they are helpful

Comment: Express in not a library for sure and yeah it is kind of homework. I've got requirement for the task - not to use anything but standard node tools. The task aim is to show what's happening under the hood and appreciate express I guess :)

Comment: I didn't mention Express. It's multer that parses body, or more specifically, busboy.  For a real case, you could go with vanilla Node+busboy or similar lib. You can check the implementation for reference, https://github.com/mscdex/busboy/blob/master/lib/types/multipart.js  Basically you need to parse data according to specs https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt

Comment: Thank you. Will look into it and hopefully understand something :)